# Как развернуть готовый nuxt проект в firebase

Tags: node.js, vue.js, firebase, nuxt.js

Имеется написанное приложение с использованием Nuxt.js. В приложении имеется подключение к firebase для хранения данных и работы с ними. Как использовать Firebase в роли хостинга и разместить на нем приложение свое, работать одновременно будут не много пользователей, я так понимаю бесплатный план подписки подходит? Попробовал сделать по имеющимся туториалам и не вышло, может руки кривые. Прошу знающих людей отписаться и подсказать как это сделать. Установил firebase-tools, залогинился а вот с остальным туго.

**UPDATE:** удалось продвинутся, нашел гайд который более менее помог разобраться в этом вопросе. [Здесь](https://dev.to/kiritchoukc/deploy-nuxt-on-firebase-4ad8)

**Следующая проблема:** после сборки приложения и запуска firebase serve на localhost:5000 (по умолчанию) отказываются работать api маршруты, не находит страницы, хотя в режиме разработки все ок. Может где-то в cloud functions что-то необходимо прописать.

**UPDATE:** Оказывается, что для api маршрутов нужна своя функция.

в functions/index.js:

```
exports.nuxtssr = require('./nuxtServer');
exports.api = require('./api/');
```

в firebase.json:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/api/**",
    "function": "api"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "function": "nuxtssr"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гайд который более менее помог разобраться в этом вопросе. [Здесь](https://dev.to/kiritchoukc/deploy-nuxt-on-firebase-4ad8)

Как оказалось, путем поисков и экспериментов, что для api маршрутов нужна своя функция.

в functions/index.js:

```
exports.nuxtssr = require('./nuxtServer');
exports.api = require('./api/');
```

в firebase.json:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/api/**",
    "function": "api"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "function": "nuxtssr"
  }
]
```